# R-Script via php exec()-function: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: php, r

I am executing an R-Script by php:

```
exec("R/firstplot.R");
```

And the R-Script is structured as follows:

```
setwd("/tmp/")

data <- read.csv("index.csv")

png("test.png")
  plot(data$index)
dev.off()
```

The content of the CSV file is very straightforward. For the sake of a minimal example one might also replace it by `rnorm(100)`;

However, upon execution i receive the following error in my apache `error.log`:

```
R/firstplot.R: 2: R/firstplot.R: 
: not found
R/firstplot.R: 3: R/firstplot.R: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Any hint on how to debug this is very welcome.

I know that there are very similar questions for other programming languages that yield the same error. However, with my limited knowledge in other language I am not able to draw conclusions form my situation described above.

Comment: That's the entirety of the script that throws the error?

Comment: yes! nothing else in it